# Fast floating point model broken on next-generation intel compiler

Tags: c++, floating-point, icc, compiler-flags, icx

### Description

I'm trying to switch over from using the classic intel compiler from the Intel OneAPI toolkit to the next-generation DPC/C++ compiler, but the default behaviour for handling floating point operations appears broken or different, in that `comparison with infinity always evaluates to false in fast floating point modes`. The above is both a compiler warning and the behaviour I now experience with ICX, but not a behaviour experienced with the classic compiler (for the same minimal set of compiler flags used).

### Minimally reproducible example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double a = 1.0/0.0;
    if (std::isinf(a))
        std::cout << "is infinite";
    else
        std::cout << "is not infinite;";
}
```

**Compiler Flags:**
`-O3 -Wall -fp-model=fast`

**ICC 2021.5.0 Output:**
`is infinite`
*(also tested on several older versions)*

**ICX 2022.0.0 Output:**
`is not infinite`
*(also tested on 2022.0.1)*

**Live demo on compiler-explorer:**
https://godbolt.org/z/vzeYj1Wa3

By default `-fp-model=fast` is enabled on both compilers. If I manually specify `-fp-model=precise` I can recover the behaviour but not the performance.

Does anyone know of a potential solution to both maintain the previous behaviour & performance of the fast floating point model using the next-gen compiler?

Comment: GCC has a similar option: `-ffinite-math-only`, enabled by `-ffast-math`, enabled by `-Ofast`, [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/j6zaqnfPE). It makes optimisations based on the assumption that NaNs do not ever occur.

Comment: @AveMilia `-ffinite-math-only` assumes that arguments and results are not NaNs **or** Infs.

Comment: @njuffa sorry, I misread the source code and replaced the inf check for a nan check. You are right.

Comment: @Yattabyte Unless `-fp-model=fast` is defined to include IEEE-754 compliant handling of Infs (and I can find no such guarantee in the Intel docs, but may be looking in the wrong place), nothing seems broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add `-fp-speculation=safe` to `-fp-model=fast`, you will still get the warning that you shouldn't use `-fp-model=fast` if you want to check for infinity, but the condition will evaluate correctly: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3P1YGe9Yd).

In the [Intel Porting Guide for ICC Users to DPCPP or ICX](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/porting-guide-for-icc-users-to-dpcpp-or-icx.html) it is stated that:

> FP Strictness: Nothing stricter than the default is supported.  There is no support for -fp-model strict, -fp-speculation=safe, #pragma fenv_access, etc. Implementing support for these is a work-in-progress in the open source community.

Even though it works for the current version of the tested compiler (icx 2022.0.0), there is a discrepancy: either the documentation is outdated (more probable), or this feature is working by accident (less probable).