# Problem with floating point compiler-optimization for double-double extended precision class in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point, compiler-optimization, double-double-arithmetic

I implemented a "double-double" class in C++. A "double-double" uses two `doubles` to increase precision. A number is treated as `number = hi + lo`, though the sum is never actually calculated because `hi + lo == hi`. Here is a shortened version of my code:

```
class doubledouble
{
public:
    double hi, lo;

    doubledouble()
    {
        hi = 0.0;
        lo = 0.0;
    }

    doubledouble quickTwoSum(const double a, const double b) const
    {
        int old;
        doubledouble out;
        double s = a + b;
        double e = b - (s - a);
        out.hi = s;
        out.lo = e;
        return (out);
    }

    doubledouble twoSum(const double a, const double b) const
    {
        double s = a + b;
        double v = s - a;
        double e = (a - (s - v)) + (b - v);
        doubledouble out;
        out.hi = s;
        out.lo = e;
        return (out);
    }

    doubledouble operator+(const doubledouble& in) const
    {
        doubledouble s, t;
        s = twoSum(in.hi, this->hi);
        t = twoSum(in.lo, this->lo);
        s.lo += t.hi;
        s = quickTwoSum(s.hi, s.lo);
        s.lo += t.lo;
        s = quickTwoSum(s.hi, s.lo);
        return(s);
    }

    doubledouble split(const double a) const
    {
        const double split = (1 << 12) + 1;
        double t = a * split;
        doubledouble out;
        out.hi = t - (t - a);
        out.lo = a - out.hi;
        return (out);
    }

    doubledouble twoProd(const double a, const double b) const
    {
        double p = a * b;
        doubledouble aS = split(a);
        doubledouble bS = split(b);
        double err = ((aS.hi * bS.hi - p) + aS.hi * bS.lo + aS.lo * bS.hi) + aS.lo * bS.lo;
        aS.hi = p;
        aS.lo = err;
        return (aS);
    }

    doubledouble operator*(const doubledouble& in) const
    {
        doubledouble p;
        p = twoProd(this->hi, in.hi);
        p.lo += this->hi * in.lo + this->lo * in.hi;
        p = quickTwoSum(p.hi, p.lo);
        return(p);
    }
};
```

My problem is that this code works in debug-mode, but in release-mode I only get normal `double`-precision. I am using the MSVC compiler and if I put a `#pragma optimize("", off)` before the class and a corresponding `on` behind it the code works (very slow of course).

I am pretty sure the problem lies in things like `t - (t - a)` which mathematically is simply equal to `a`, so the compiler probably optimizes it like that. To narrow down the problem, I tried putting `#pragma optimize` around certain functions. But even if I put every single function inside the class between pragmas, the code does not work correctly.

Either way, using `#pragma optimize` is not very useful anyway. The code is slow and it is not portable. My first question is: Why does `#pragma optimize` not work inside for specific functions inside the class? That would be really useful to narrow down the problem.

Second question: How could I trick/convince the compiler to not optimize certain expressions like `t - (t - a)`? Using a temp-variable would probably not work, because the compiler would optimize that away.

**Edit**

As a reproducible example I used this code:

```
double a = 1.23456789012345;
const double split = (1 << 12) + 1;
double t = a * split;
double hi = t - (t - a);
double lo = a - hi;
   
std::cout << "hi: " << hi << ", lo: " << lo << std::endl;
```

Output in both cases (release- and debug-mode):

```
hi: 1.23457, lo: -3.48832e-13
```

So `t - (t - a)` does not seem to be the problem.

As for a "simple" example (if I find a simpler one, I will edit) that produces the wrong behavior - I calculated the mandelbrot-set with zooms greater than 10^14. In debug mode I got perfect results, in release mode I get pixelation. I used this function to create the images:

```
void CalcMandelCPU_doubledouble(std::atomic<unsigned int>* RowCounter)
    {
        std::complex<doubledouble> Z, C;

        int Y = (*RowCounter)++;
        while (Y < ResY)
        {
            for (int X = 0; X < ResX; X++)
            {
                C.real(minX + (X + 0.5) * (maxX - minX) / ResX);
                C.imag(minY + (Y + 0.5) * (maxY - minY) / ResY);

                int i;
                Z = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < MaxIter; i++)
                {
                    Z = Z * Z + C;

                    if (Z.real() * Z.real() + Z.imag() * Z.imag() > 4.0)
                        break;
                }

                if (i == MaxIter)
                {
                    Result[Y * ResX + X] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    Result[Y * ResX + X] = i + 1 - log(log(Z.real() * Z.real() + Z.imag() * Z.imag())) / log(2.0);
                }
            }
            Y = (*RowCounter)++;
        }
    }
```

Define `MaxIter`, `ResX` and `ResY`. `minX`, `maxX`, `minY` and `maxY` will give you the (zoomed) view. Examples for the view-variables (as `doubledoubles`) :

`minX.hi = -1.9997740601362948`, `minX.lo = 9.2915246622385581e-17`

`maxX.hi = -1.9997740601362861`, `maxX.lo = 7.5150963188138267e-17`

`minY.hi = -3.2900430992572130e-09`, `minY.lo = 1.7490722630808694e-25`

`maxY.hi = -3.2900375437016574e-09`, `maxY.lo = 1.0427104313278710e-25`

Comment: Try `t - double(t - a)` ?

Comment: What does that mean exactly " but in release-mode I only get normal double" ? How do you verify the resulting precision? The compiler will not turn `t - (t - a)` into `-a` unless it can prove the equivalence

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: The compiler will happily perform that optimization in [`/fp:fast` mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior?view=msvc-170)

Comment: "The `/fp:fast` option allows the compiler to reorder, combine, or simplify floating-point operations to optimize floating-point code for speed and space. The compiler may omit rounding at assignment statements, typecasts, or function calls. It may reorder operations or make algebraic transforms, for example, by use of associative and distributive laws. It may reorder code even if such transformations result in observably different rounding behavior"

Comment: @BenVoigt `doubledouble` is not floating point operations

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I wrote "...but in release-mode I only get normal double precision". I tested this with a simple function that calculates the mandelbrot-set. With double-precision you get pixelation at a zoom of around 10^14. With "double-double"-precision you can get to around 10^28 before that happens. I am not sure if `t - (t - a)` is the problem, but years ago I read a paper about "double-doubles" and if I remember correctly, they said to turn of compiler-optimization for certain parts of the code and I believe this was one of them.

Comment: "Under `/fp:strict`, the compiler generates code that allows the program to safely unmask floating-point exceptions, read or write floating-point status registers, or change rounding modes. It rounds to source code precision at four specific points during expression evaluation: at assignments, typecasts, when floating-point arguments get passed to a function call, and when a function call returns a floating-point value. Intermediate computations may be performed at machine precision. Typecasts can be used to explicitly round intermediate computations."

Comment: I might be off, but in any case you should post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. I suppose a simple `main` with an example of `t - (t-a)` would suffice

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: Of course it is (doing floating-point operations).  `doubledouble::operator+()` is filled with floating-point operations.  But I am pretty sure that "`t - (t-a)`" in the question is not even talking about `doubledouble`.

Comment: @BenVoigt oh, got it. It talks about `out.hi = t - (t - a);`

Comment: Can you give a concrete (and simple) example use of the class that produce the wrong behavior?

Comment: I found one example where the optimziation kicks in when `-ffast-math` is set https://godbolt.org/z/aKez8fGn5, without the flag: https://godbolt.org/z/hdzdaK868, and with the flag disabled in the source: https://godbolt.org/z/Txz6nan6r

Comment: Generally a compiler is not allowed to optimize floating point operations in a way that will change the result except for assuming higher precision in intermediate results than its floating point type permits inside an expression, but not across assignment or casts. So adding casts should force rounding to actual type precision, assuming the compiler is configured to be standard-conforming (e.g. for GCC this is not the default and bugs do exist). But even with that, are you sure that your arithmetic accounts properly for rounding direction, NaN, infinity, etc.?

Comment: Imho the proper solution is to simply not use `-ffast-math`. It breaks IEEE compliance anyhow https://stackoverflow.com/a/22135559/4117728

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Even without it isn't going to work the way OP expects.

Comment: @user17732522 without a proper example that works as OP expects in debug mode and exhibits different results when optimizations are disabled imho this quesitons isnt answerable. I was just trying out something to see an effect, but eventually only OP knows what they expect

Comment: I edited the question. As mentioned - `t - (t - a)` is not the problem. Calculating the m-set does show pixelation in release mode that is not there in debug mode. I will try different simple approaches and see, if I can find a simpler example than the code in the edit.

Comment: `std::complex` has unspecified behavior when used with anything but the (built-in) floating point types. You need to check that your implementation supports this use case.

Comment: @user17732522 Good point - but using the mandelbrot function without `std::complex` gives the same result...

Comment: Something completely different, why are you using 12 in the split function? The idea is to split the mantissa in half, so that there is no loss in multiplications, the products of the halves fits completely into the full number type. For single precision the halves are 12 bit long, but for double precision 27 bit.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I have a variant of this code that uses 29 here. I got these values from two different papers years back and I was wondering the exact same thing - why not use  half the mantissa, so26 or 27? I just tried 27 and it didn't change a thing, though...

Comment: `double t = a * split;` gets rounded to `double`, or at least it does in the ISO C++ abstract machine.  If you're compiling 32-bit code for legacy x87 FP, it might not, depending on how strict the FP math optimization options are.  Or if you're compiling for `/arch:AVX2` so hardware FMA is available, the compiler might contract ` t - (t - a);` into `a*split - fma(a, split, -a)`, that would skip the rounding of `t`.  (And could further contract to a chain of just two FMSUB instructions.)  I think that's actually *good* for precision, though, since you only get one rounding in `a*split - a`.

Comment: What architecture are you compiling for?  What optimization and FP options?  Also, testing your expression with a compile-time-constant `a` hardly proves anything.  The question is what asm it makes for run-time computations, which might be different from compile-time constant-propagation.  (Which is what happens for math on constants when you enable optimization.)

Comment: Also, why is `split` a non-`static` member function?  It doesn't use `this->hi` or `this->lo` at all.

Comment: Re: “A ‘double-double’ uses two doubles to increase precision” — i wasn’t able to find a reference this, but I recall reading that some early mainframes used pairs of floats to gain precision, and referred to operations on these pairs as “double precision”.

Comment: @Paul Aner: Generally speaking, two items usually help avoid unwanted re-association of floating-point expressions: (1) Assign the result of each arithmetic operation to a variable, i.e. no multi-operation floating-point expressions. E.g. `double s =  t - a; double r = t - s`. (2) For MSVC specifically, use `/O2` in conjunction with `/fp:strict` or at least `/fp:precise`. Put the `/fp` switch last on the command line. Under no circumstance use any "fast math" flags.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm compiling for x64, optimization is /O2, /fp is fast. I couldn't find an /arch option, but I can use AVX2 and AVX512 so I think it should be set to that somewhere. But I think what is "good" for precision is actually a problem here, because a lot of the calculations are for catching rounding errors and putting them into the `lo`-part. Is it possible to deactivate this for certain code sections? I don't want to switch off optimizations globally for performance reasons.

Comment: @All: I generally don't want to deactivate optimizations globally if they are just a problem with this particular class.

Comment: @PeteBecker: "double-double-precision" is not "quad-precision" and "float-float-precision" is not "double-precision". This approach effectively doubles the size of the mantissa. So 23 bits of a float become 46 bits, not 52 bits of a double. Also this does not extend die exponent. So for "float-floats" this stays 8 bits, for doubles 11 bits.

Comment: `/fp:fast` - well there's your problem!!!   That allows the compiler to treat FP math as associative, allowing `t - (t-a)` to optimize to `(t-t) - -a = +a`.  Double-double requires strict FP; the whole point of `split` is to use FP rounding before subtraction to cancel part of the mantissa bits.  (So definitely not `fast` math, strict vs. precise I'm not sure.  You don't need FP exceptions, so options like that don't matter, only rounding of temporaries and perhaps contraction into FMA or not.)

Comment: I remember reading that FMA helps significantly for overall efficiency with double-double, but I'm not sure it's safe to  think you'd only want to use that intentionally.  Or maybe it works either way, with or without rounding `a*scale` before subtraction.  Anyway, see also [Optimize for fast multiplication but slow addition: FMA and doubledouble](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30573443) re: using SIMD double-double for Mandelbrot fractals.

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed - `/fp:strict` does work. Still: I would rather not change global optimization settings, to not slow down the rest of the code. Is there a possibility to switch to `strict` for some of the code or trick the compiler to not reorder the operations? If I use a temp variable, so `out.hi = t - (t - a)` -> `temp = t - a; out.hi = t - temp;` wouldn't the compiler optimize `temp` away?

Comment: @PaulAner — a 46-bit mantissa has twice as much precision as a 23-bit one, hence, double **precision**. Not `double` precision.

Comment: Well, since back in the good old days computers probably did not have **certain** `highlighting`, that means "double precision" != "double precision". I just wanted to explain the difference between "floatfloat"/double and "doubledouble"/quad precision for interested readers. ;-)

Comment: "A "double-double" uses two doubles to increase precision" - Ehh, *no*. There's no such thing as a "double double".

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: @JesperJuhl: double-double isn't the name of a C++ type, it's the name of a numerical technique that uses two `double`s.  It does exist, see the tag [tag:double-double-arithmetic], and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic .  If you mean that `double double` doesn't exist as a C or C++ type, you're correct, but nobody's claiming that.  Note the hyphen in the name, not a space.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Re "I remember reading that FMA helps significantly for overall efficiency with double-double". It helps mostly with multiplication, cutting operation count roughly in half (the splitting technique is not needed). It helps to improve the performance of double-double division and square root.

Comment: @njuffa: Do you happen to know if contraction breaks `split()`, like if `a*scale - a` computed with an FMA still works?  If that's not ok, GCC needs `-ffp-contract=off` (because its default `fast` will contract across statements.)

Comment: @Paul Aner `/fp:precise` usually does not have a major negative impact on application-level performance if one has a requirement that computations should actually be correct. Conversely, if results are allowed to be wrong, any code can be made arbitrarily fast. You can explicitly code `fma()` where you want / need it when you build with `/arch:AVX2` or `/arch:AVX512` and it will map to the HW instructions. You can also add `/favor:INTEL64` when building for an Intel platform, although I have not observed any noticeable performance gains.

Comment: @Peter Cordes To the best of my recollection, the answer is "sometimes yes, sometimes no". It depends on the details of how contractions are applied. I recall at least one instance where the splitting was working properly despite the compiler applying contractions; I analyzed that in detail from the disassembly to figure out why it happened to work in that case. To be absolutely certain that the split for double-double multiplications works correctly, one would want to disable contractions, though. Even better: explicitly code with FMAs, as HW support for FMA is near universal now.

Answer (score 3):

Write only single operations, using a cast or assignment to isolate each assignment.

The C++ standard allows an implementation to use excess precision in expression evaluation but requires casts and assignments to use the nominal precision. So `double x = t - (t - a);` may be implemented as if it had infinite precision, and then it is mathematically equal to `a`, so optimization may reduce it to `a`. However `double x = t - static_cast<double>(t - a);` must produce a `double` value for the cast. `double t0 = t - a, x = t - t0;` also must produce a `double` value for `t0`.

(Technically, the implementation could use excess precision for the subtraction, including rounding, and then round it to `double`, allowing the possibility of a double rounding error, but I have not heard of this happening.)

Note this assumes standard-conforming behavior. If the compiler has been licensed to perform additional optimizations, as with a switch telling it to be looser with math than the standard specifies, the methods in this answer may be insufficient.

---

#### Some compiler details

Mainstream compilers are generally fine when compiling for x86-64 which implies using SSE2 for floating point so the hardware format is IEEE754 64-bit `double`.  Same for most other modern ISAs like PowerPC and ARM / AArch64.  So math should be IEEE compliant as long as you **avoid options like MSVC `/fp:fast`** or GCC/Clang `-ffast-math`.

GCC's default (with the default `-std=gnu++20` or whatever) is `-fexcess-precision=fast`, so you'll want `-fexcess-precision=standard`, or `-std=c++20` which implies that, if you're compiling for **32-bit x86 with x87 floating-point**.  (SSE2 doesn't have this problem).  MSVC targeting x86 with x87 FP sets the FPU precision-control bits so all results are rounded to a 53-bit mantissa (so it's like `double` except for the exponent range), avoiding the need for store/reload to actually round to `double`.  (Or if you linked at Direct3D library, it'll set the precision-control to 24-bit, `float` mantissa width, according to [Bruce Dawson's excellent articles from 2012](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/) about FP math in general and MSVC/Windows in particular.)

GCC's default is `-ffp-contract=fast`, which will allow it to contract `t - a` into `fma(a, scale, -a)` even across statements when FMA is available (like `-march=x86-64-v3` when compiling for x86-64).
MSVC's default is [`#pragma fp_contract off`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/fp-contract?view=msvc-170); clang's default is `-ffp-contract=on` (within one expression, not across statements, like ISO C `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT on` (also [supported by some C++ compilers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/impl))).  (GCC doesn't support `on`, only `off` and `fast`, so GCC's `on` is equivalent to `off`: the only way to stop its optimizer contracting across statements is to disable it entirely.)

Classic ICC's default is `-fp-model fast=1`, so for this you'd need `-fp-model precise`.  See also [slides from a 2012 talk about FP math optimization in ICC and GCC](https://indico.cern.ch/event/166141/sessions/125686/attachments/201416/282784/Corden_FP_control.pdf).  The LLVM-based ICX [doesn't have the same options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73534181/fast-floating-point-model-broken-on-next-generation-intel-compiler), being more like Clang.

Other compilers default to MSVC `/fp:precise` or gcc/clang `-fno-fast-math`.

Comment: Rounding twice: that's what you'd expect from x87 with `gcc -ffloat-store` `-fexcess-precision=standard` or other strict-FP math option, if the x87 precision control is left at max, so 64-bit mantissa.  i.e. `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2`.  But MSVC  initializes the precision control so all ops round to a 53-bit mantissa.  https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/ .  See https://godbolt.org/z/rb85P5b1r - the GCC default is `-fexcess-precision=fast`, so it won't round even for `static_cast<double>(t - a);`

Answer (score -1):

OK, here is the solution:

Switching from `fp:fast` to `fp:strict` as mentioned by multiple users in the comments solves the problem. However, I did not want to change global optimization settings to not effect the rest of my code. The solution was to put `volatile` before certain variables (if there is a better solution, please comment). Indeed only two changes were necessary:

Function `twoSum`:

```
doubledouble twoSum(const double a, const double b) const
    {
        volatile double s = a + b;
        volatile double v = s - a;
        double e = (a - (s - v)) + (b - v);
        doubledouble out;
        out.hi = s;
        out.lo = e;
        return (out);
    }
```

... and function `split`:

```
doubledouble split(const double a) const
    {
        const double split = (1 << 26) + 1;
        volatile double t = a * split;
        doubledouble out;
        out.hi = t - (t - a);
        out.lo = a - out.hi;
        return (out);
    }
```

Thank you to the commenters.

Comment: Yeah `volatile` can work to force that value to be rounded to an actual `double`, but I thought you wanted to use this for the inner loop of Mandelbrot fractals.  Adding store/reload latency (about 5 to 6 cycles) to the dependency chain in the inner loop is very bad.  How much slower is this than just using `/fp:strict` for that file?  (If you don't use link-time optimization, each source file can be built with different optimization options.  Of course, disabling LTO is also a significant penalty if your project has small functions in .cpp files rather than .h which need to inline.)

Comment: Using `/fp:strict` instead of `volatile` looks a bit faster. I didn't time it, though. Could you think of a better and faster method than `volatile` to force rounding / not-reordering for the above lines?

Comment: Not that I know of with MSVC.  With GCC or Clang or ICC, you can force a value to be materialized in a register (and used as the value of that variable going forward) with `asm("" : "+x"(t));` - it's an asm statement with the C variable `t` as an input/output operand, requiring it in an XMM register.  (So this is specific to x86 / x86-64).  So it's effectively `t = black_box(t)` for the optimizer.  (But not `asm volatile` so the compiler can assume `black_box()` is a pure function of its input, in case that helps any.)  It will also defeat auto-vectorization and const-propagation.

Comment: In GCC / Clang, some options can be applied per-function, like `__attribute__(("no-fast-math")`, although the manual says (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) that attribute is not suitable for production use, only debugging.

Comment: Please don't advocate `volatile` as a solicitation. There are *very few* situations where that's the right solution and this does not look like one of them.